# Dynamic create and communicate with QWidget from terminal

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I am developing an experimental platform, which is based on python terminal. The basic requirement is as follows.

In python terminal, I will load 3D images and do some image processing on these 3D images. At a certain point, I want to visualize the intermediate results. So I need to develop a GUI interface, which is callable from terminal and doesn't block the terminal when the GUI is displayed.

Besides this requirement, I also need to control the GUI from terminal. For example, if I type ">> viewer.zoom(2.0)", I expect the image in the viewer will be zoomed in by a factor 2. So basically I need to communicate between terminal and QtGUI.

I am new to Qt development. According to the documentation listed on the official website (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html), it is not supported to create a GUI in a separate thread. So right now I have no idea how to implement this type of platform.

Can anyone give me a few hints on how to do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The GUI can be in a separate process, and you can easily communicate line-based commands and responses between the controlling process and the gui. But the GUI doesn't have to block anything of course, if you invert the control in your Python project so that everything runs from the event loop, then the event loop won't be a blocker as long as your other code doesn't block.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to use Process from multiprocessing module to pass a function to instantiate a process. The function just creates a QApplication, create and display a default QWidget. When I ran it, the program crashed... Can you suggest a way to create a process displaying a GUI? and how to communicate between controlling terminal and GUI in different processes? Thanks.

Comment: The gui-displaying process is literally a separate application. You just start it using the `subprocess` module in Python.

Comment: @KubaOber OK. Then could you recommend a way to communicate between a GUI subprocess and the terminal process? I need to pass both small message (e.g., command type, coordinates), and also a big image data to the GUI process.

Comment: When you launch a process, you have an open bidirectional communication channel with it by default. You can close this channel and setup another one, like a pipe, if you wish, of course. Start with `subprocess` docs to see the comm channel.